# How to use a single backslash in string interpolation in Sass

Tags: sass

I want to generate this CSS with a **Unicode** character code:

```
.foo::before {
  content: '\4556';
}
```

Concatenating a single (unescaped) backslash (`\`) with the code (e.g. `4556`).

With the main condition that I don't want to have to provide the Unicode codes already prepended with the backslash (e.g. `\4556`) but to generate them from an integer for example. Like in the following mixin:

```
@mixin make-icon ($name, $code) {
  .#{$name}::before {
    content: '\#{$code}';
  }
}

@include make-icon('foo','4556');
```

However the above mixin returns this CSS:

```
.foo::before {
  content: '\#{$code}'; }
```

I've tried `'\\#{$code}'`, `'\##{$code}'`, `'/\#{$code}'`, `'\/#{$code}'`, `'\$code'`, `'\\##{$code}'` and none of them gives the desired result.

Even tried defining slash as a variable and interpolate it but that didn't help either.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass variable interpolation with backslash in output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608762/sass-variable-interpolation-with-backslash-in-output)

Comment: it's not a duplication of that one because my codes don't have `\` in the beginning. But that would be one solution. However, I'm curious to learn how to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.  The fact that you're using a string and the other question is using a number doesn't change anything.  The problem is the same and the solution is the same.

Comment: Sir, my question is different. It is the leading slash character that causes the problem. The solution to that question requires me to put the slash in my code. I don't want that. Martin Turjak's answer is the correct answer which doesn't require me to add the slash at the beginning of my codes.

Comment: In Sass 3.4.13, try solution on there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111982/sass-3-4-removing-forward-slash-on-a-string/26112274#26112274

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sass **v3.3** you can get around this problem by using the new `str-slice()` function and doing something like this:

```
@mixin make-icon ($name, $code) {
  .#{$name}::before {
    content: str-slice("\x",1,1) + $code;
  }
}

@include make-icon('foo', 4556);
```

which should output:

```
.foo::before {
  content: "\4556";
}
```

### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8881632)

Comment: Why didn't you just flag to close this question as a duplicate and provide an answer to the original non-duplicate question?

Comment: @cimmanon I have thought about it a bit ... and I have come to a conclusion that the answer to the other question offers a sufficient solution to the specific problem there ... although it is true that the discussion shows that both posters wondered if there was a way of using a single backslash in string interpolation. Anyway, I rewrote the question here a tiny bit ... so that it is more specifically asking just about that ... which, I think, makes it more likely for other people to find and less of a duplicate (but I it might still be borderline ;-)

Comment: This example works for old versions of sass, but with the latest version as of right now (v3.4.13) doesn't support this working. Here is a question which addresses the issue for later versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26112274/1203288

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, @MartinTurjak solution is not entirely working for me, but I was finally able to get it working with `SASS maps`

```
//node-sass 4.11.0
//libsass 3.5.4

$hexes: (
           checkmark: \2714
        );

@function out-content($var) {
    @return unquote("\"#{ $var }\""); 
}

@each $mod, $code in $hexes {    
    .#{$mod}-after {
        &:after {
            content: out-content($code);
        }
    }
}

//output
//.checkmark-after:after {
    //content: "\2714";
//}
```