# SCSS Processor Unicode Output Incorrect

Tags: unicode, sass, font-awesome

I have tested this issue using Scout-App and Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

Having just downloaded [Font-Awesome 4.7.0 SCSS files](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/) and set up a project/workspace, I have noticed a problem with unicode output. As an example:

in the '_variables.scss' partial, we have:

```
$fa-css-prefix: fa;
$fa-var-music: "\f001";
```

and in '_icons.scss' partial, we have:

```
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-music:before { content: $fa-var-music; }
```

with an expected result of:

```
.fa-music:before { content: "\f001"; }
```

but the output is:

```
.fa-music:before { content: ""; }
```

So all the unicode values stored in variables are processed to ``

Thus I am unable to correctly compile the correct output for a modified font-awesome CSS file.

I have tried placing UTF8 encoding at the top of each SCSS file but the issue is still unresolved.

For a quick test, this will produce the result described:

**test.scss**

```
@charset "UTF-8"; 
$fa-css-prefix: fa;
$fa-var-music: "\f001";
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-music:before { content: $fa-var-music; }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow user2631949 is  \f001 a valid unicode? do you have a font thats supports this code? Your output looks valid Ref https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f001/browsertest.htm

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f001/index.htm

Comment: Yes, it is the unicode value that Font-Awesome uses to map to a specific icon in their font files. Another example, which also fails to output the the unicode value stored in the variable and instead, produces:

    $fa-css-prefix: fa;
    $fa-var-home: "\f015";
   .#{$fa-css-prefix}-home:before { content: $fa-var-home; }

and the output is:

    .fa-home:before { content: ""; }

Which is no longer going to point to the correct icon. You can see all the unicode mappings on the [Font_Awesome Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet)

Comment: Hi user2631949 Which method di you use to install the fonts for Font-Awesome? did you install them locally or on a server? Desktop / local https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started Serve https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself  I ask because you're report seems to indicate the Font-Awesome fonts are not installed / accessible

Comment: No problems installing downloaded CSS Font-awesome and using on my website. Trying to use their SCSS file to process a cut down version of just the fonts I need. I could do it by hand but I'm trying to automate the process as intended by SCSS technology but latest version fails to process the unicode values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems by writing:

```
"\f0a9" ,
```

Scout will compile the unicode character.

But, if you use interpolation:

```
#{'"' + \f0a9 + '"'}
```

then Scout will compile to "\f0a9".

You can also use variables like

```
$escaped: \f0aa;
...
#{'"' + $escaped + '"'}
```

or:

```
$escaped: f0aa;
...
#{'"\\' + $escaped + '"'}
```

Remarks:

- The compiled unicode character may become a problem to the browser in the content attribute. Therefore you want to give him the written hex code.
- If you mess around with the backslash and the interpolation, see also here:
  [Sass variable interpolation with backslash in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608762/sass-variable-interpolation-with-backslash-in-output)